# Phyton, getting ValueError: No tables found matching pattern

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
f = open("G:\WNBA\wnba_id.txt", "r")
print(f)
for id in f:
    matchid.append(id)
  
_url_template = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/{}"

for x in matchid:
    formatted_url = _url_template.format(x)
    print(formatted_url)

    df=pd.read_html(formatted_url, match='(Q1)')
    for i in df:
        
        new=i.assign(match_id=x)
        new.to_csv("G:\WNBA\wnba_Q1.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

I get this error:[image]

It worked fine till 2 weeks ago...now the problem is that the script works, i don't know why i get this error because the table Q1 exist and it's properly imported into my csv file; the only problem is that sincei want to add some other scraping line after this in the same file, getting the error it is got stopped and i've to launch individually every other script (specifing that they work but they all give the same error as this one i posted). Any clue to get rid of this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with:

```
f = open("G:\WNBA\wnba_id.txt", "r")
print(f)
for id in f:
    matchid.append(id)
```

At some point in your txt file, it's appending an empty string.

How do I know?

You did a good thing here by including the `print(formatted_url)`. We can see exactly at what point in your code it breaks. Looking at your console output, we see:

```
https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/202208120ATL
https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/202208120MIN
https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/202208120PHO
```

This is followed by:

```
https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/
```

, meaning there is an empty string going into `"https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/{}"`

So take a look at that file, and see what's after `'202208120PHO'`

You can also fix this in the code, by not appending empty strings into the `matchid` list.

```
f = open("G:\WNBA\wnba_id.txt", "r")
print(f)
for id in f:
    if id.strip() != '':
        matchid.append(id)
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem; wheni paste in the txt file every new match, closing the file with the cursor at the end of first string works (even id i didn't understand why)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be due to the syntax used to match? Does

```
df=pd.read_html(formatted_url, match='Q1')
```

work? As brackets aren't needed to match something with read_html().
[panda Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

Comment: No the brackets are for the correct match of the tab, not intended as a part of the command